# Finding the sum of a geometric binomial progression

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

**By considering $x^{n}+x^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(1+x\right)+x^{\left(n-2\right)}\left(1+x\right)^{2}+...+\left(1+x\right)^{n}$, find the sum of $\begin{pmatrix}n\\ r\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}n-1\\ \:r-1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}n-2\\ \:\:r-2\end{pmatrix}+...+\begin{pmatrix}n-r+1\\ \:\:1\end{pmatrix}$.**

I have found the sum of the Sum GP to be $$\frac{x^{n+1}-\left(1+x\right)^{n+1}}{2x-1}$$

Now, if I consider $x^{n}+x^{\left(n-1\right)}\left(1+x\right)+x^{\left(n-2\right)}\left(1+x\right)^{2}+...+\left(1+x\right)^{n}$, I tried to find the term $x^r$ which works well EXCEPT for $\begin{pmatrix}n-r+1\\ \:\:1\end{pmatrix}$. The term of this is not $x^r$, but $x^{n+2}$ which is out of place. By my way, the final term should be $\begin{pmatrix}n-r\\ r-r\end{pmatrix}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does $2x-1$ come from? Isn't this just $(1+x)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}$ ?

Comment: Also I suggest to not use $()$ for powers as that suggests Pochhammer symbols, and since you're doing combinatorics, it could as well be that.

Comment: yes you are right my sum GP was wrong

Comment: Did you find a way to incorporate the sum formula into the proof?

Answer (score 1):

The required can be re-written as
$$S=\sum_{j=1}^{r} {n-(j-1) \choose r-(j-1)}=\sum_{j=1}^{r} {n-(j-1) \choose n-r}=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} {n-k \choose n-r}$$
$$\implies S=[x^{n-r}]~~ \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} (1+x)^{n-k}=[x^{n-r}]\left((1+x)^n \frac{(1+x)^{-r}-1}{(1+x)^{-1}-1}\right)$$
$$S=[x^{n-r}]~~ \left( (1+x)^n \frac{(1+x)^{-r+1}-(1+x)}{-x}\right)$$
$$S=[x^{n-r+1}] ~~ ((1+x)^{n+1}-(1+x)^{n-r+1})$$
$$S={n+1 \choose n-r+1}-1= {n+1 \choose r}-1$$

Here $[x^j]~ F(x)$ means the coefficient of $x^j$ in $F(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this solution

Comment: In the third step, you let $k = j - 1$ right?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Ok makes sense. I don't understand line 2 (how you got rid of the summation notation)

Comment: Because the GP with common ratio as $(1+x)^{-1}$ has been summed up.

Comment: And also I don't get line 4 to 5 - did you distribute the parenthesis? What coefficient of $x$ did you consider to get it back into combinatorics notation?

Comment: Oh (for line 2) did you just change summation notation into a sum by using Sum of GP = $\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$?

Comment: yes, down is it $1-(1-x)$, remember that $[x^j] (f(x)/x)$ means [x^{j+1}] f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, what are you referring to by "down"?

Comment: down means denominator.

Comment: Ah ok. In line 2 or from line 4 to 5?

Comment: from line 4 to 5.

Comment: Wait but there's no denominator in lines 4 or 5

Comment: OK it should be 5 to 6 then.